# Maya 'merge' the list of shapes, polyBridge, Extrudes etc

Tags: performance, maya

Couldn't come up with a good way of googling this..
I'm working on a 3d model in Maya and it's getting slow. At first I couldn't find what it was, but I'm suspecting it's all of the polyBrideEdge, pCubeShape and whatnot. Since I was duplicating one part and repeated that a couple times; there's quite a lot of them.

Here's a screenshot of what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHCC7.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found it! For anyone wondering: you select one of the nodes with the same type in your attribute editor and click 'hide'. This will group them together I suppose and name it 'polyUniteX'. It might not be the best way or the right way, but this has fixed any performance issues I had prior to doing this.

Comment: If your model is getting slow you might want to consider deleting construction history https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-delete-history-in-maya